# Mysterious bottom padding/margin issue

Tags: html, css, height

I have a main div with the class of .features, inside this div I have two boxes each one with a height set to 160px and different widths. There's a myterious padding between the end of the two boxes and the main div as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

The padding is about 5px - I would like to remove this padding if possible. I tried adding margin: 0; and padding: 0; to the main div as well as to the two inner boxes but it didn't work.

Here is the html for this section of the page:

```
<div class="features">
    <div class="list-items"></div>
    <div class="screenshot-box"></div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
 .features {
    width: 980px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.list-items {
    width: 280px;
    height: 160px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}

.screenshot-box {
    width: 583px;
    height: 160px;
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code on fiddle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with `padding` or `margin`. If we look at the computed style example, we'll see that the `height` of the element itself is `164px`:

[image: Example]

This is happening because your inner elements are set to display as `inline-block`. This means they're affected by `font-size`, and ultimately the `font-size` is causing the height of the parent element to be greater than the height of the inner elements.

There are two fixes:

1. Specify a `font-size` of `0` on your `.features` element, and then reset this within the inner elements (by giving them a `font-size` of `16`, or whichever your default size is).

```css
.features {
  width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 0;
}

.list-items {
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.screenshot-box {
  width: 583px;
  height: 160px;
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
    <div class="list-items"></div>
    <div class="screenshot-box"></div>
</div>
```

2. Give your `.features` element a `height` of `160px` itself to match its children. With this the browser doesn't have to calculate what the height should be itself.

```css
.features {
  width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 160px;
}

.list-items {
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.screenshot-box {
  width: 583px;
  height: 160px;
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
    <div class="list-items"></div>
    <div class="screenshot-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks James, I went with the font size approach as I'd the parent element to expend it self as new content is added on. Now, I understand why that padding was there. I'm learning a bit more each day. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just make `font-size` as 0 for `.features`, and it will take full width. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/m3onov03/) is your fiddle.

```css
.features {
  width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 0;
  /*Just make font size as 0*/
}
.list-items {
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
.screenshot-box {
  width: 583px;
  height: 160px;
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
  <div class="list-items"></div>
  <div class="screenshot-box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just ditch the `display: inline-block` on both child elements and set `float: left` on `.list-items` and `display: table` on `.features` ([code example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOMMdE)). Added benefit that without hardcoded parent div height, the parent div will expand to fit child content.

@james donnelly has already given you an accurate and concise explanation to the cause.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to take this approach as historically different browsers have handled table-displaying elements differently, and floated elements (neither `table-row` nor `table-cell`) aren't really intended to be placed within them. A better approach to using `float` on both elements would be to clear the floats afterwards.